# W3C's down down menu bugging

Tags: javascript, menu, dropdown

[www.mesogom.com/umass/](http://www.mesogom.com/umass/)

If you check the link you see I'm having a lot of bugs here. I'm trying to figure out why it spaces out the  so much vertically. I changed the onclick to onmouseover in the JS, but having these JS/CSS issues. Any help appreciated.

Here is the JS:

```js
/* When the user hovers on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
    
// Close the dropdown menu if the user mouses outside of it
window.onmouseover = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the W3C have to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. The issue you're having with swapping out `click` for `mouseover` is the way you're checking `event.target`. It will only be matched when your mouse is directly over `.dropbtn` and not any children. There is, however, an [`event.currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) which will always match the element your event handler was attached to. This would be the correct usage:

```
document.querySelector('.dropbtn').addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
     if (event.currentTarget...)
});
```

While it's not typical SO fashion to suggest an different language for a solution to a question, I strongly recommend you consider a CSS solution for any hover menus. Much simpler, and preferred nowadays. [WC3 has a great tutorial on that.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp). However, if you're planning on making your website mobile friendly, you may want to stick with a click menu (you can't hover very well on mobile). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would use CSS but javascript was a requirement for class. As for W3C i got the code from their website. Good pointer on the mobile-friendly clicking. Went back to the old code now all I have to do it seems is fix some CSS bugs. Thanks